# Replace NA with value from another column with corresponding column name

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4   Last_Col1    Last_Col2   Last_Col3    Last_Col4
  NA       1       4        7           9           10          11           12
  NA      NA       4       NA          NA            9          NA           10
   8      NA       9       10          11           12          20           49
   9       7      NA       NA          34            2           3           50
```

How do I replace the NA values without `Last_` in the beginning of the name with with the corresponding columns with `Last_` in the name? I then want to remove the columns that have `Last_` in the name.

Final expected output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4   
   9       1       4        7    
  NA       9       4       10    
   8      12       9       10    
   9       7       3       50
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is the corresponding columns, we subset the columns that have 'NA' to be replaced ('nm1') and the columns having 'Last' as prefix ('nm2'), create a logical matrix on the first set of columns ('i1'), use that to assign the values of the second set of values that corresponds to `NA`

```
nm1 <- names(df1)[1:4]
nm2 <- names(df1)[5:8]
```

Or use

```
nm1 <- names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), "Col")]
nm2 <- names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), "Last_")]
i1 <- is.na(df1[nm1])
df1[nm1][i1] <- df1[nm2][i1] 
newdf <- df1[nm1]
newdf
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1    9    1    4    7
#2   NA    9    4   10
#3    8   12    9   10
#4    9    7    3   50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(NA, NA, 8L, 9L), Col2 = c(1L, NA, NA, 
7L), Col3 = c(4L, 4L, 9L, NA), Col4 = c(7L, NA, 10L, NA), Last_Col1 = c(9L, 
 NA, 11L, 34L), Last_Col2 = c(10L, 9L, 12L, 2L), Last_Col3 = c(11L, 
 NA, 20L, 3L), Last_Col4 = c(12L, 10L, 49L, 50L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! For nm1, is there a way to do it where you say something like, does not start with "Last_"? Each of my column names are actually different with the exception of the "Last_".

Comment: @nak5120  In that case, create the logical index based on the 'Last' column names, use `!` to negate the TRUE to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE for subsetting the column names.  Note that you can subset the columns with just logical vector.  I just subsetted the names to make it more obvious  `i <- startsWith(names(df1), "Last_"); nm1 <- names(df1)[!i]; nm2 <- names(df1)[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Split the data into two data.frames, find which are missing in those designated `Col_X` and overwrite them with values from the data.frame that starts with `Last_`.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4   Last_Col1    Last_Col2   Last_Col3    Last_Col4
  NA       1       4        7           9           10          11           12
  NA      NA       4       NA          NA            9          NA           10
   8      NA       9       10          11           12          20           49
   9       7      NA       NA          34            2           3           50", header = TRUE)

xy1 <- xy[, grepl("^Col\\d+$", names(xy))]
xy2 <- xy[, grepl("^Last_Col\\d+$", names(xy))]

xy1[is.na(xy1)] <- xy2[is.na(xy1)]

> xy1
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    9    1    4    7
2   NA    9    4   10
3    8   12    9   10
4    9    7    3   50
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution (will be very fast on bigger datasets):

```
ourcols <- paste0("Col", 1:4)
for (col in ourcols) {
  rows = which(is.na(dt[[col]]))
  set(x = dt, i = rows, j = col, value = dt[rows, get(paste0("Last_", col))])
}
dt[, ..ourcols]
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1:    9    1    4    7
2:   NA    9    4   10
3:    8   12    9   10
4:    9    7    3   50
```

Comment: It may be better to extract the column `[[` first

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.. could you please explain?

Comment: What I meant is that when you do `dt[rows, get(..`  there would be an overhead of data.table.  Instead if you extract the column `dt[[get(paste`, may be that overhead is removed.  I find this [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902786/difference-between-select-and-in-r) useful though it is not directly related to here